# Set Rocket.Chat Server (snap) to only listen on localhost

Tags: ubuntu, server, localhost, rocket.chat, snap

I'm struggling to find documentation on how to change the Rocket.Chat snap server installation to only listen on localhost. I want to use a reverse-proxy to allow access to the service.

```
$ sudo snap get rocketchat-server
Key                Value
backup-on-refresh  disable
ignore-errors      false
mongo-oplog-url    mongodb://localhost:27017/local
mongo-url          mongodb://localhost:27017/parties
port               3000
siteurl            http://localhost:3000
```

Can I adjust settings in `/var/snap/rocketchat-server/current` to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Rocket.Chat's Community Manager here :)

Rocket.Chat (or any server, for that matter) will need to bind to a port under an IP. Otherwise the reverse-proxy will not be able to communicate with it.

if you want to restrict traffic to that port from specific sources, you will need to do so using your firewall.

With that said, here we have a nice FAQ about our SNAP:
https://docs.rocket.chat/deploy/prepare-for-your-deployment/rapid-deployment-methods/snaps/snap-faq

Also, please, consider using docker or kubernetes as your deployment method. For docker, follow: https://docs.rocket.chat/deploy/prepare-for-your-deployment/rapid-deployment-methods/docker-and-docker-compose

Let me know if this helps :)

Thanks!